# Не подключается lib-библиотека С++ к C# проекту

Tags: c#, c++, dll

- Я скачал библиотеку
- Добавил в настройках поддержку общеязыковой среды выполнения(CLR)
- Добавил библиотеку в моё решение
- В С# проекте установил на неё ссылку

  Но при попытке собрать проект, получаю ошибку:

> Ошибка    C1190   System::Object не найден, отсутствует параметр /clr или отсутствует импорт стандартных сборок

Comment: Добавление в настройках общеязыковой среды выполнения не дает возможность автоматически использовать эту библиотеку из под c#. Даже не факт, что она после этого может корректно собраться и работать. Скорее всего, вари придется ее переделывать.

Comment: И не подключится. DLL можно подключить. lib - на прямую нет.

Comment: Если уж вы решили собрать с++ с lib отдельным проэктом (что б dll получилась) то С# тут не уместен, а если у lib существуют зависимости - то вам нужно в проэкт подключить зависимости.